# set telerik radwindow header title

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Im using teleik RadWindow object, and Im use RadWindow.HeaderTemplate to set in the header an icon and a textblock.

When i press Alt+Tab to show the open winsows i see the window with title "RadWindow".

How can i set the title to the content of the textblock?

My code:

```
<telerik:RadWindow.HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemContainerTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
         <Image source="../gears.ico"/>
         <TextBlock Text="settings"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </ItemContainerTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow.HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :)

```
>     TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
>     textBlock.Text = "My RadWindow";
>     textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
>     RadWindow radWindow = new RadWindow();
>     radWindow.Width = 400;
>     radWindow.Height = 300;
>     radWindow.Header = textBlock;
```

Comment: It doesnt work. If i do RadWindow.Header = "window name" its work, but Im use HeaderTemplate